# How to check in JSP if user is logged (using JSTL <if> statement), and display username?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am aware there are many similar questions on SO - most of them referring to implement this concept with servlet filters.

I am using form based, declarative security approach. And, when some user, on login form enters his(or her) credentials (username and password), he is being redirected to certain/secured jsp page. Part of that page content is:

```
Hello <%=request.getUserPrincipal().getName().toString()%>
    You are able to view this page because you are authorized user.
```

Now, if user is logged in, I would like display his/her username, no matter if its secured jsp page or not. Something like this:

```
<c:if test="${statement that checks if some user is logged in}">
   User: ${username of the logged user here}
</c:if>
```

**EDIT**
I would also like to replace JSP scriptlet part: `<%=request.getUserPrincipal().getName().toString()%>` with appropriate JSTL command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing `pageContext` object in both situations, `request` by itself is not implicit object in JSP page.

```
<c:if test="${not empty pageContext.request.userPrincipal}">
    User <c:out value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}" />
</c:if>
```

And JSTL equivalent for `<%=request.getUserPrincipal().getName().toString()%>` is: `<c:out value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}"/>`

Comment: Whops... forget about that. That is what happens when answering without trying it...  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

```
<c:if test="${not empty pageContext.request.userPrincipal}">
    User: <c:out value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}" />
</c:if>
```

Use `c:out` to correctly escape printed values and prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: tried that, but nothing shows up, like if the `if` statement is not `true` (btw, i have included `jstl core taglib`)

Comment: well, when user logs in then his name on the secured page (code above, in the question part) is displayed. So, it should be set. I tried going through several other jsp pages, coming back to this secured page, and it shows its logged user.

Comment: +1 for `c:out`. @Wlad: are you sure, that your principal is in request and not in session scope?

Comment: @Kojotak i tried with `${sessionScope.userPrincipal.name}` but still nothing displays. Basically, I don't know how to retrieve name of the logged and authorized user. And it is logged and authorized, because its name is displayed as stated in java scriptlet tag in jsp.

Comment: @Kojotak how can I use `jstl` instead of `<%=request.getUserPrincipal().getName().toString()%>`?